# Pass string literal as the argument to the print function with out any format specifier?

Tags: c

Why I am not getting error even though I am not not passing any format specifier but passing a string literal. There is no error in the case of string literal but there is an error in the case of character,integer. Why ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   printf("Hello World");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is your code that shows an error?

Comment: Since the first parameter is a const char *, then when you have a nul-terminated c-string named `sz`, realize that `printf(sz);` behavior can be different than `printf("%s", sz);`, e.g. sz contains % characters.  In your example, "Hello, Word" c-string happens to work the same for both (but not necessarily).

Comment: "Hello World" is a valid format.

Comment: I guess OP tried something like `printf(42)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on printf is as follows:

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

Print formatted data to stdout
Writes the C string pointed by format to the standard output (stdout). If format includes format specifiers (subsequences beginning with %), the additional arguments following format are formatted and inserted in the resulting string replacing their respective specifiers.
putting a char or int variable in place of format above will fail

Answer (score 5):

The first argument to `printf` should be a format string<sup>1</sup>. `"Hello World"` is a format string<sup>2</sup>.

Per paragraph 7.21.6.1 3 in the C 2018 standard, the format string is composed of zero or more directives:

- A `%` character starts a directive for a conversion specification.
- Any other character is a directive to output that character unchanged.

So `"Hello World"` is a format string that says to print “H”, “e”, “l”, “l”, “o”, “ ”, “W”, “o”, “r”, “l”, and “d”. It is simply a format string with only ordinary characters, no conversion specifications. It is the proper type and data for the first parameter of `printf`, so no errors occurs.

In contrast, when a `char` or `int` is passed as the first argument to `printf`, the compiler knows it is the wrong type for the argument and issues a warning or error message.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Technically, the argument should be a pointer to the first character of the format string.

<sup>2</sup> `"Hello World"` is passed as a pointer because, while it is an array of characters, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first character.

Comment: Literally the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with a help of preprocessor and [Generic Selection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) introduced in C11 to select a proper format string basing on argument's type.

Try:

```
#define FMT(X) _Generic(X, int: "%d", char*: "%s", float: "%f") 
#define print(X) printf(FMT(X), (X))
```

Now the program:

```
int main() {
   print(1);
   print("abc");
   print(3.0f);
   return 0;
}
```

Produces an expected output of `1abc3.00000`.